# PHP Warning : PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll

Tags: php

when I try to run command "PHP" I have an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib
/php/20151012                                                                                                                 
/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll:
cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/li
b/php/20151012
/php_pdo_oci.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_oci.dll: cannot open 
shared ob 
ject file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/
php/20151012
/php_pdo_oci.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_oci.dll: cannot open 
shared ob 
ject file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/
php/20151012 
/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_odbc.dll: cannot 
open shared 
object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib        
/php/20151012
/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_pgsql.dll: cannot 
open share 
d object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/
php/20151012
/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_sqlite.dll:
cannot open sha 
red object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to install PHP-mbstring and PHP-Intl but it still not works.

I am running in PHP 7.0 with debian 9.
I don't know what to do now.

thanks for answering !
(sorry for my bad English ^^)

Comment: Paste your error in the question, instead of an image.

Comment: Why did you remove the error from your question? I had asked you to place the error instead of link to an image.

Comment: sorry , now i think it's better

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `../php/php.ini` file and check if all those **.dll** files shown as warning are enabled or not. If not enabled, then enable them. If issue still persists, then check your `../php/ext` folder to see if you have those **.dll** files present there. Or else you have to manually download and paste them in that folder.

Comment: thanks for answer , i enabled all extentions but it's doesn't work , i downoalded dlls , and it's still not works i have a new error message : "Invalid ELF header" .

Comment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_firebird.dll: invalid ELF header in Unknown on line 0`
(and this for 5 other libraries)

Comment: Did you restart your `apache` or whichever server you are using, after making the above changes?

Comment: yeah il restarded apache2 "service apache2 restart" but it's don't work